# Python PyTd teradata Query Into Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, teradata

I'm using the `PyTd teradata` module to query data from Teradata and want to read it into a Pandas DataFrame

```
import teradata
import pandas as pd

# teradata connection
udaExec = teradata.UdaExec(appName="Example", version="1.0",
                           logConsole=False)
session = udaExec.connect(method="odbc", system="", username="", password="")

# Create empty dataframe with column names
query = session.execute("SELECT TOP 1 * FROM table")
cols = [str(d[0]) for d in query.description]
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols)

# Read data into dataframe
for row in session.execute("SELECT * FROM table"):
    print type(row)
    df.append(row)
```

`row` is of `teradata.util.Row` `class` and can't be appended to the dataframe. I tried converting it to a list but the format gets messed up.

How can I read my data into a dataframe from Teradata using the `teradata` module? I'm not able to use the `pyodbc` module for this.

Is there a better way to create the empty dataframe with column names matching those in the database?

Answer (score 5):

You can use pandas.read_sql :)

```
import teradata
import pandas as pd

# teradata connection
udaExec = teradata.UdaExec(appName="Example", version="1.0",
                           logConsole=False)
with udaExec.connect(method="odbc", system="", username="", password="") as session:


    query ="SELECT * FROM table"

    df = pd.read_sql(query,session)
```

Using ‘with’ will ensure close of session after the query. I hope that helped :)

Answer (score 0):

I know its a little late. But putting a note nevertheless.

There are a few questions here.

> How can I read my data into a dataframe from Teradata using the
>   teradata module?

At the end of the day, a teradata.util.Row is simply a list. So a simple list operation should help you get things out of Row.

```
','.join(str(item) for item in row)
```

kinda thing.

Pushing that into a pandas dataframe should be a list to df conversion exercise.

> I'm not able to use the pyodbc module for this.

I used teradata's python module to do a LDAP auth. All worked fine. Didn't have this requirement. Sorry.

> Is there a better way to create the empty dataframe with column names matching those in the database?

I assume, given a table name, you can query to figure it schema (table names) >> convert that to a list and create your pandas df?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is very late.

You can use read_sql() from pandas module. It returns pandas dataframe.

Here is the reference:
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/generated/pandas.read_sql.html