# Python Teradata Connector - Column Names

Tags: python, teradata

Does anyone know how to retrive the column names using Python's Teradata libary..?

Here is a code sample:

```
import teradata
udaExec = teradata.UdaExec (appName="HelloWorld", version="1.0" logConsole=False)
session = udaExec.connect(method='odbc', system='system_name',authentication='LDAP', username='username', password='$$tdwallet(tdprod)');
lst_results = []
for row in session.execute("select * from table_name"):
 print(row)
 lst_results.append(row)
```

The code above will not return the column names.  Ultimately, I would like to put the query's results into a Panda's dataframe

Answer (score 0):

You do not need for-loop:

```
df = pandas.read_sql(session,query)
```

Will do the job. See my answer here:

[Python PyTd teradata Query Into Pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37850181/python-pytd-teradata-query-into-pandas-dataframe/46523589#46523589)